# unable to put correlation coefficient on scatter plot on shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I need to put correlation coefficient on my scatter plot on shiny app. Below is the example I made to illustrate my problem. The correlation text just does not show on the plot. The checkbox seems to be non-responsive. I took long time trying to figure out why, but couldn't. Can anyone let me know what I did wrong? Thank you very much in advance.

```
#--------------------functions------------------------------------------
corr_eqn <- function(x,y, method='pearson', digits = 2) {
    corr_coef <- round(cor.test(x, y, method=method)$estimate, digits = digits)
    corr_pval <- tryCatch(format(cor.test(x,y, method=method)$p.value, 
                                 scientific=TRUE),
                          error=function(e) NA)
    paste(method, 'r = ', corr_coef, ',', 'pval =', corr_pval)
}

sca.plot <- function (cor.coef=TRUE) {
    df <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl==4)
    p<- df %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x=hp, y=mpg))+
        geom_point()+
        geom_smooth()
    if (cor.coef) {
        p<- p+geom_text(x=0.9*max(mtcars$hp),
                        y=0.9*max(mtcars$mpg),
                        label = corr_eqn(df[['hp']],df[['mpg']],
                                         method='spearman'))
    }
    return (p)    
}

#-------------------------ui----------------------------
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            checkboxInput('cor.cplot', 
                          label = h5('Correlation Coefficient'), value = TRUE)
        ),
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput('plot') 
            )
        )
    )
#---------------------------server---------------------------------

server <- function(input, output) {


    output$plot <- renderPlot ({
        sca.plot(cor.coef = input$cor.cplot)
    })
}


runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geom is working fine, the text just ends up way beyond the limits of your plot since the location is calculated based on maximum values from mtcars rather than df.

This should work

```
p <- p + geom_text(
  x = 0.9 * max(df$hp),
  y = 0.9 * max(df$mpg),
  label = corr_eqn(df[['hp']], df[['mpg']],
                   method = 'spearman')
)
```

Might want to use geom_label for readability

```
p <- p + geom_label(
  x = 0.9 * max(df$hp),
  y = 0.9 * max(df$mpg),
  label = corr_eqn(df[['hp']], df[['mpg']],
                   method = 'spearman')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `annotate()`. Also, note that you may want to set the `x` and `y` for the text using the data in your plot rather than the whole dataset. For this, you may use `p$data$hp` instead of `mtcars$hp`.

```
p <- p + ggplot2::annotate("text", x= 0.9*max(p$data$hp, na.rm = T),
                           y = 0.9*max(p$data$mpg, na.rm = T), 
                           label = corr_eqn(df[['hp']],df[['mpg']],
                                            method='spearman'))
```

This is the result

[image]